# Error : Supabase url is required , Python

Tags: supabase, supabase-py

I've been faced SupabaseException: supabase_url is required.
Here are codes

```
import os
from supabase import create_client, Client

url: str = os.environ.get('https://mine.supabase.co')
key: str = os.environ.get("xxxxminexxx")
supabase: Client = create_client(url, key)
```

SupabaseException: supabase_url is required.

supabase version : 1.0.4
python : 3.10.9

i don't know how to deal with this problem.
Plz help.

1. make account supabase https://supabase.com/
2. pip install supabase
3. Run code
4. Error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  That isn't how ```os.environ``` works.  It expects a ```key: value``` pair, so whatever your variable your URL is defined as, you get that and not the actual value itself.  i.e.  if os.environ has ```URL=http://...."```,  you do a ```os.environ.get("URL")```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the environment variables from the operating system you should be checking for the variable name which you can setup with dotenv python package or a normal `export SUPABASE_URL="my-url-to-my-awesome-supabase-instance"` and not a url or anon_key as you have in your example. Take a look at the example below which is also outlined in the [Supabase Python docs](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/python/initializing)

```
import os
from supabase import create_client

url = os.environ.get("SUPABASE_URL")
key = os.environ.get("SUPABASE_KEY")
supabase = create_client(url, key)
```